# remove all drawing in imageview UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: swift, null, imageview, cgpoint, uigraphicscontext

I want to remove everything written imageview pic. I have tried something like pic.Clear() but its not being recognized. I dont know what else to do. The only other thing I can think off is to somehow create a variable that is like a line because I cant access the lines right now outside of the func they are in now. I am trying to do this is in clearM. Using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext has something to do with this. I dont want to use pencil kit.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var startPoint: CGPoint?
    var statPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var swipe = false
    var pic = UIImageView()
    var clearBtn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [pic,clearBtn].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        pic.backgroundColor = .brown
        clearBtn.backgroundColor = .blue
        pic.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 250)
        clearBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 350, width: 50, height: 50)
        clearBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearM), for: .touchDown)
    }
    
    @objc func clearM(){
    
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return}
        swipe = false
        statPoint = touch.location(in: self.pic)
    }

    var score = 0

    func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint : CGPoint)  {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( pic.frame.size)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }
        
        pic.image?.draw(in: pic.bounds)
        context.move(to: fromPoint)
        context.addLine(to: toPoint)
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.setLineWidth(5)
   
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context.strokePath()
        
        pic.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        pic.alpha = 1

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }
        swipe = true
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: pic)
        drawLine(from: statPoint, to: currentPoint)
        statPoint = currentPoint
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !swipe {
            drawLine(from: statPoint, to: statPoint)
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pic.frame.size)
        pic.image?.draw(in: pic.bounds, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        pic.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reassign original image to your image view for clear all drawing.

Comment: I dont know how to do that?

Comment: In your code you have created one clear button and added target. So inside the target action set original image to your image like pic.image = yourImage. If you don’t set any initial image then write simply pic.image = nil